# Is there a way to make an empty array and growing it as it gets data in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listview

I have been working on a project, and am attempting to make a new array for data. I have tried making an empty array with Dim Name() As String = {}. I am using a ListView, and the way I have done it there are blank spots where I have gotten rid of data. This is my current code:

```
    Sub English(ByVal Country() As String, ByVal Language() As String)

    rbDisplayallData.Checked = False
    lstResults.Visible = True
    lstResults.Items.Clear()
    lstResults.Columns.Clear()

    With lstResults
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Add("English Speaking Countries", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    End With

    For i = 0 To 181
        Dim EnglishSpeakingCountries(i) As String
        If Language(i) = "English" Then
            EnglishSpeakingCountries(i) = Country(i)

        End If
        lstResults.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({EnglishSpeakingCountries(i)}))

    Next
End Sub
```

[I am trying to get rid of these spaces.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC6UQ.png)

I Was thinking if I were to compact the array or make a new one with the same data going into a new array it would fix the issue.

If you have a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that could be considered an empty array

1. An array with no elements, i.e. a `Length` of zero.
2. An array where every element is `Nothing`.

All arrays are fixed-length. Once you create an array with a particular number of elements, it always has that number of elements.  You can use `ReDim Preserve` or `Array.Resize` but, in both those cases, what actually happens is that a new array is created and the elements copied from the old array.  The new array is assigned to the same variable but anywhere the old array is referenced, it will still have that same number of elements.  Try running this code to see that in action:

```
Dim a1 As String() = {}
Dim a2 As String() = {"First", "Second", "Third"}

Dim b1 = a1
Dim b2 = a2

Console.WriteLine(a1.Length)
Console.WriteLine(a2.Length)
Console.WriteLine(b1.Length)
Console.WriteLine(b2.Length)

Console.WriteLine()

ReDim Preserve a1(2)
Array.Resize(a2, 6)

Console.WriteLine(a1.Length)
Console.WriteLine(a2.Length)
Console.WriteLine(b1.Length)
Console.WriteLine(b2.Length)

Console.ReadLine()
```

Output:

```
0
3
0
3

3
6
0
3
```

As you'll be able to see, `a1` and `a2` end up referring to new arrays with the specified lengths but the original arrays with the original lengths still exist and are still accessible via `b1` and `b2`.

If you start with an array with no elements then you can use `ReDim Preserve` or `Array.Resize` to give the appearance of resizing the array but that's not really what's happening and that should generally be avoided.  If you know how many elements you'll end up with then you could create an array of that size and then set each element in turn.  You'd need to keep track of the next element index though, so that's still a bit tedious.

Generally speaking, if you want an array-like data structure but you want it to be able to grow and shrink as required, you should use a collection.  The most common collection is the `List(Of T)`, where `T` is any type you care to specify in your code.  If you want to store `String` objects then use a `List(Of String)`.  You can call `Add` to append a new item to the end of the list, as well as `Insert`, `Remove` and `RemoveAt` methods.  You can also get or set an item by index, just as you can do for array elements.

Note that a `List(Of T)` actually uses an array internally and uses the aforementioned method of "resizing" that array.  It optimises the process somewhat though, which makes the code easier for you to write and large collections more efficient to use.

It's worth noting that, in your own code, the `Columns` and `Items` properties of your `ListView` are both collections, although they are slightly different to the `List(Of T)` class.

Looking at your original code, this:

```
For i = 0 To 181
    Dim EnglishSpeakingCountries(i) As String
    If Language(i) = "English" Then
        EnglishSpeakingCountries(i) = Country(i)

    End If
    lstResults.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({EnglishSpeakingCountries(i)}))

Next
```

could be changed to this:

```
Dim englishSpeakingCountries As New List(Of String)

For i = 0 To 181
    If Language(i) = "English" Then
        englishSpeakingCountries.Add(Country(i))
        lstResults.Items.Add(Countries(i))
    End If
Next
```

Note that you're just adding items to two collections.  I guess the question is whether you actually need this extra collection at all.  If you do want to use it later then you need to assign it to a member variable rather than a local variable.  If you don't need it later then don't create it at all.  As I said, you're already adding items to a collection in the `ListView`.  Maybe that's all you need, but you haven't provided enough info for us to know.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to programming, and my knowledge of it is slow for now. I am running the code you posted and was getting 0,3,0,2    3,6,0,3. I do not really understand where the 6 came from. I appreciate the help. I need to do a lot more research into what you are suggesting in order to do it.

Comment: My answer has been updated with the aforementioned "more" that was to follow.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the help. I'll do more research into List(Of T) and Array.Resize. I need to get better at doing research, but I did not know where to start. Thanks

Comment: I have posted all of my code, and a picture of the problem that I am having. In the future is that something I should do or should I just give snippets of the code?

Comment: You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to post a good question, particularly creating a minimal, verifiable example. There was no need for you to post anything else because I've provided everything you need. The blank items in your `ListView` were due to adding items outside the `If` block, which I have already addressed here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll check out the Help Center. Take care.